# Using the Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, storyboard

I am using the `storyboard` in xcode and have 2 `View Controllers` and linking it to each other.  I have a photo button that brings up the camera on the first `View Controller` and I want to show and save the picture that I took on the second `View Controller` on the `storyboard`.  Is that possible using the storyboard or do I have to make another file?

Comment: Yes, you have to make another file (not another storyboard). See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547756/setting-outlet-action-for-view-controller/16548851#16548851

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. After picking the photo, call the first view controller method `performSegueWithIdentifier` to go to the second view controller and in the `prepareForSegue` you can pass the photo.

Answer (score 0):

or save the photo to a common data object, or file.